# API in excel to retrieve WIX database JSON file

Tags: javascript, vba, api, velo

I am trying to find out how to automatically export my data from WIX with an API call. I know this will be in JSON format and will have to be parsed in excel.

So far my js code on the wix back end looks like this:

```
import { ok, notFound, serverError } from 'wix-http-functions';
import wixdatra from 'wixdata';

export function my_function() {
   let options = {
    "headers": {
       "content-type": "application/Json"
   }
};
return wixData.query("database table name")
.find()
.then(results => {
   if (results.items.length > 0) {
       options.body ={
           "items": results.items
       }
       return ok(options);
    }
  }
}
```

And my VB code looks like this:

```
 Dim hReq As Object, Json As Dictionary
 Dim sht As Worksheet
 Dim authKey As String
 authKey = "xxxkeyxxx"
 Set sht = Sheet1
 Dim strUrl As String

 strUrl = "https:endpointurl"
 Set hReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With hReq
      .Open "GET", strUrl, False
      .setRequestHeader "Authorization", authKey
      .Send
    End With

 Dim response As String
 response = hReq.ResponseText
 MsgBox response

 End Sub
```

I imagine both codes are probably wrong for a number of reasons but I am really out of my depth here! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For 2, start with any API documentation. Is there any?

Comment: What do you mean by that? I have set up an API key on Wix, I am going to try enabling http function and exposing the API key as mentioned below by Sam

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 will work, with some modification, for any email provider that exposes an API for sending emails.

I'm not exactly sure what you mean in option 2, but it sounds like you can create an [HTTP function](https://support.wix.com/en/article/velo-exposing-a-site-api-with-http-functions) on the Velo side that will expose data from a database collection as an API. Then you can call that API from any third party system.

Comment: I woke up this morning and tried one more google search https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4yCBplV3MPQ - found this link which is exactly what you said for option 2! Hopefully it works, will let you know!

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note, which I am guessing you have discovered is that the JSON returned has the data you want, nested within an "items" JSON key pair, and you will need to parse that out one side or another...